# Object Collision C#

Tags: c#, collision-detection, collision

I have Been Developing a game, I am having problems with the collision part of this game, and I'm not sure how to fix it

```
    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Obstacle> removed = new List<Obstacle>();
        foreach (Obstacle o  in obstacles_)
        {
            Rectangle bounds = o.Bounds;

            if (players_[0].Bounds.IntersectsWith(bounds))
                removed.Add(o);             
        }
        foreach (Obstacle ob in removed)
            obstacles_.Remove(ob);
    }
```

Basically what I need it to do is if the player runs into an object, then it will remove itself from the list and stop being drawn on the form.

EDIT - Realised I haven't really said what the problem is, When the object collides, it doesn't remove itself, and continues to be drawn

Edit - 2 FIXED - See comment below!

Comment: http://www.gamedev.net/page/index.html

Comment: You'll need to be more specific. What isn't working? Is it throwing an error? Is the object not removed from the list?

Comment: show code where you use "obstacles_" in program like print and add or other methods..!!!!

Answer (score 0):

My first guess would be that you're using a different list of objects in the draw step than in the collision step. If you're removing the objects from obstacles_ but in the draw step you iterate through objects_, for example, the objects would still be drawn.

Another problem could be if the obstacles_ list is rebuilt every step. I would suggest stepping through this block, make sure the objects are actually removed, then checking the draw step and see if the list is up to date (the object is gone). If you can, start with one obstacle to make it easy on yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys, thanks for all the help, I have managed to figure it out, I was creating the bounds in the obstacle class at the start of the code, but then as it updated its position the bounds didnt update...

Seem sorta foolish but I think ive got it all sorted now.

Thanks for everyone that tried to help!